# GitHub API to get all changeset without iterating all branches

Tags: java, github, github-api

GitHub has Api to find commits from repository path 
https:///api/v3/repos/demouser/TestRepo/commits

if I have 1000 branch  + master and find all commits after given date, then i need to iterate all branch and send request to https:///api/v3/repos/demouser/TestRepo/commits/ which has performance impact at git repo.

Is there any API which returns me all changesets by giving all or selected branch?

Comment: I am not sure i understand your question.  Do you want to find all the commits made on a particular repository after a given date?

Comment: yes, commits may be on different branch but wants all commits on repository